# Magento 2: Can't switch from developer to production: "Command returned non-zero exit code:"

Tags: magento2, deploy, developer-mode

I've seen two other threads with this issue but I have been unable to resolve it with the solutions provided.

I've increased my memory limit to 1G in php.ini and I've set `ini_set('memory_limit','2G');` right under my `<?php` tag in bin/magento.

In PuTTY I run; 
`/usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/lfcstage/public_html/bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`
which returns; 
    Command returned non-zero exit code:
    `php -f /home/lfcstage/public_html/bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US 2>&1`

However, when I run;

```
/usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli /home/lfcstage/public_html/bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

it completes successfully so I don't understand why I still can't toggle my mode back to production from developer.

I'm hosted on a cloud solution with SiteGround. 
Specs: 1 x 3.0 GHz CPU Cores, CentOS, 2GB RAM, 20GB SSD, cPanel, Cloud Storage, Management Services

Comment: Try to add "-vvv" key to your console command. It should give you more details about the error.

Comment: @Aus-tn did you find a resolution? I'm with siteground cloud and encounter the same issue.

Answer (score 7):

Turns out Magento was not able to compile on my SiteGround build. I could switch it back when I ran;

```
/usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
```

Stay away from SiteGround with Magento 2 IMO, clean installs of Magento 2 just do not work.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this issue by using these commands.

Run this commands

1. sudo php bin/magento maintenance:disable
2. clear cache
3. sudo chmod 777 var* -R
4. sudo chmod 777 pub* -R

Comment: Setting anything to 777 is never the answer

Comment: @Mageician, thats not true. if you are running it just for you on a VM then it does not mather at all. But never do this on shared hosting.