# Change to Production mode the Theme something error

Tags: model, magento2.2.4, production-mode

Change to Production mode the Theme something error
but developer mode is working , how can i do?
please help! thank you!

my command:

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s --skip-compilation
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: try below solution :
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121231/magento-2-cant-switch-from-developer-to-production-command-returned-non-zero

Comment: i can finish to changed the mode , the magento working but the theme some like css or JavaScript missed. i already ran bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US but same the problem. how can i do? thank you @shail

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
sudo rm -rf var/cache/*; sudo rm -rf var/di/*; sudo rm -rf var/generation/*; sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*; sudo rm -rf pub/static/*;
php -f bin/magento deploy:mode:set production -s
php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: i found the problem is JavaScript and Css Setting Enable, JavaScript Bundling and Minify caused. @JAKE THE GREAT